# Pulling product price to new block

Tags: php, magento2.4

I have added a new block to my product page. In the block i want to display the product price so I can then take that price and divide it by 3 to show monthly payments. I have tried to get the price by copying code used in other phtml files but it's not even displaying the price.

Can someone advise on what i need to do in order to get the price to show?

Here is the code i have so far in my phtml file.

```
<div class="klarna_calc">
    <img class="klarna_logo" src="/media/Klarna_logo_bw.svg" alt="Klarna logo"/>
    <i class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
    <p>Price 
        <?= $price = $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getDisplayValue()) ?>
        <?php echo $price; ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Object Manager(Not Recommended)

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');//get current product
echo $product->getPrice();
?>
```

Using block

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;
class BlockClass extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
}

?>
```

Call function in your .phtml file:

```
<?php
$currentProduct = $block->getCurrentProduct();
echo $currentProduct->getPrice();
?>
```